# SQL Server - best replication model for archiving

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, replication, archive

I am at the point where I need to start archiving database of website I'm maintaining. Basically, lots of transactional data is generated daily, and after approximately 2 weeks, this data is pretty much useless - it is still needed for reporting purposes, but it can be safely moved from production server.

So, ideally I would love if I could do this:

1. Setup pull replication - backup server hourly fetches changes from production server.
2. Daily - production server database is cleaned - entries older than 2 weeks are deleted.

On #1 - I am curious if pull replication is the most efficient way to go from performance standpoint? I don't want to put strain on production server (or at least not a big strain)... I don't care much about keeping databases in sync.

On #2 - How to make sure that these deletes are not replicated - that data is kept on archive server?

Production server runs SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, Backup server can run whatever needed (currently it runs SQL Server 2008 Express)

Comment: For #2 you won't want to use replication or mirroring because the deletes will happen on the replica as well. In general I'd suggest partitioning, or manual archiving to a separate database, but you forgot to tell us which version and edition of SQL Server you're using - those are important details.

Comment: I've added details... was also looking into partitioning, maybe that + pull replication for backup/reports is the way to go...

Comment: You won't be able to use replication for backup/reports as that will delete the old data when you delete it from the source.

Comment: If you use replication, you won't be able to use SQL Express as the subscriber (or publisher or distributor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, I'd say test it out and see.  MS typically has a couple of whitepapers saying that pull subscriptions are more performant, but I don't recall them saying what it costs in terms of resources.  If you're worried about it, set up a remote distributor (remote = not the same server as the publisher)

For #2, there are a couple of ways to do it.  When you set up the article with sp_addarticle, there's a parameter @del_cmd which can take a value of "none".  This will tell the distribution agent to no-op deletes at the subscriber.  You could also do your purging with a stored procedure, set up the execution of the stored procedure as an article in replication and then have a stored procedure at the subscriber that does nothing.  Each approach has its pros and cons.

Comment: #1 Pull subscription spawns distributor on the machine that's pulling, so it's definitely the best when it comes to performance (server with original database only publishes changes to local replication db and that's it)... #2 Useful info... will see if I can somehow use it, although I'll probably resort to writing procedures that will copy data I need to Archive DB.

Comment: For #2 The solution you described using a stored procedure that would do deletes and then have the same stored procedure that did nothing on the subscriber sounded like it would be a great solution for us, however I've set it up and tested it and it seems that the data is deleted at the subscriber as well.  Perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: Actually I just noticed that creating the stored procedure as an article in the replication smashed my dummy one in the subscriber, so I'm guessing it copied the sp that performed the deletes and then executed it on the subscriber?

Comment: Still couldn't get the dummy stored procedure method to work, I'll go ahead and go with the option "don't replicate delete statements".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your Mar 16 replies.  For the problem that you were having with the article initialization resulting in the overwriting of the stored procedure at the subscriber, that should be controlled by the @schema_option in the call to sp_addarticle.  Specifically, if the 0x01 bit is set, it will behave as you describe.  If not, then it shouldn't replicate the sproc schema.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  I think I'm having trouble because I don't understand how SqlServer behaves for replicating deletes to the subscriber.  By default it seems it calls sp_MSdel_dbo<tablename> to replicate deletes to the subscriber, for the tables I care about you can use @del_cmd = N'NONE' like you describe in your answer, but are you suggesting setting del_cmd = N'CALL [dbo].[your_dummy_stored_proc]' instead?  Or is the fact that the stored proc to do deletes is an article, it won't use the default sp_MSdel_dbo<tablename> on those tables to replicate the changes? Thanks.

Comment: Ah... no.  What I'm suggesting is creating a stored procedure at the publisher that handles deletes in the general case.  Let's call it dbo.DeleteRecords.  You're going to create an article for the stored procedure execution.  Now, when you execute dbo.DeleteRecords, it'll delete the records at the publisher and then execute the sproc at the subscriber. The magic happens when that sproc at the subscriber is coded to do nothing.  Replication is smart enough to know that the deleted records at the publisher were the result of the sproc execution, and so won't replicate the deletes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional explanation, I'll give it another try.

Comment: I've tried it again using the stored proc to do my deletes, for the delete SP I even specify "Execution in a serialized transaction of the SP" for the article (@type = N'serializable proc exec' in sp_addarticle) and when I look at what happens on the subsriber it still calls: exec [dbo].[sp_MSdel_... instead of my delete stored pro.  Thanks for your help, but perhaps I should just ask a separate question on this in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I look forward to helping you when you get a separate question going.  One thing to note is that serializable proc exec will replicate the proc as individual row commands under certain circumstances.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152754.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm waiting to create a new question because I'm re-thinking the model of archiving through replication.  My concern is that even if I get it setup correctly, the method is susceptible to human error.  Say if for some reason somebody creates a new snapshot and the subscriber refreshes to it, suddenly we've lost all our archived data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we should apply the partition for tables archiving. If you setup replicaion and archive data older than two weeks, the problem is when reinitialize replication, all data on subscribers will be delete and apply new data from publisher.